# Get files from directories alphabetically sorted with bash

Tags: bash, sed, find

I have this code that works in the directory that I execute:

```
pathtrabajo=.
filedirs="files.txt"
dirs=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | sort -n)
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for entry in $dirs
do
    echo "${entry}" >> "${filedirs}"
    find "$entry" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.md' -printf '%f\n' | sort | sed 's/\.md$//1' | awk '{print "- [["$0"]]"}' >> "${filedirs}"    
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

But when I try to make it global to work with variables, `find` gives error:

```
pathtrabajo="/path/to/a/files"
filedirs="files.txt"
dirs=$(find "${pathtrabajo}" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | sort -n)
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for entry in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    echo "${entry}" >> "${pathtrabajo}"/"${filedirs}"
    find "${entry}" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.md' -printf '%f\n' | sort | sed 's/\.md$//1' | awk '{print "- [["$0"]]"}' >> "${pathtrabajo}"/"${filedirs}"    
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try running with the code with the debug flag enabled. bash -x ....

Comment: Why do you temporally assign IFS to "\n\b"?

Comment: So that the variables in $ {dirs [@]} are separated in newlines

Comment: But that would be `IFS=$'\n'`; what's the `\b` for?

Answer (score 1):

It's really not clear why you are using `find` here at all.  The following will *probably* do what you are trying if I can guess from your code.

```sh
dirs=([0-9][!0-9]*/ [0-9][0-9][!0-9]*/ [0-9][0-9][0-9][!0-9]*/ [!0-9]*/)
printf "%s\n" "${dirs[@]}" >"$filedirs"
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\n" "$dir"/*.md |
    awk '{ sub(/\.md$/, ""); print "- [["$0"]]" }'
done >>"$filedirs"
```

The shell already expands wildcards alphabetically. The `dirs` assignment will expand all directories which start with a single digit, then the ones with two digits, then the ones with three digits -- extend if you need more digits -- then the ones which do not start with a digit.

It would not be hard, but cumbersome, to extend the code to run in an arbitrary directory. My proposed solution would be (for once!) to `cd` to the directory where you want the listing, then run this script.